# Как убрать лишние (пустые) строчки из массива и пересчитать его (переиндексировать с нуля)

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день. Имеется массив. Как можно убрать лишние строки из него и пере индексировать. Мне необходимо получить такой-же массив, чтобы не было пустых элементов. Исходный массив

```
$movies = array(
array(
),
array(
),
array(
"0" => "surname",
"COLUMN_NAME" => "surname"
),
array(
"0" => "phone",
"COLUMN_NAME" => "phone"
),
array(
"0" => "Name",
"COLUMN_NAME" => "Name"
)
);
```

Желаемый массив

```
$movies = array(
array(
"0" => "surname",
"COLUMN_NAME" => "surname"
),
array(
"0" => "phone",
"COLUMN_NAME" => "phone"
),
array(
"0" => "Name",
"COLUMN_NAME" => "Name"
)
);
```

Пустые строки массива могут содержаться как вначале, так в середине или конце массива. По этому, мне необходимо, чтобы и индексы массива верхнего уровня были переиндексированы. Т.е. данный результат можно было вызвать с помощью.

```
$movies[0][COLUMN_NAME], $movies[1][COLUMN_NAME], $movies[2][COLUMN_NAME] и т.д.
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Осталось понять какие же из них лишние...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подробней о `array_filter()` - [array_filter().](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)
Удаляем сперва пустые "клетки", а потом просто вытягиваем значения из вышедшего массива функцией [array_values().](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)

```
$movies = array(
    array(
    ),
    array(
    ),
    array(
        "0" => "surname",
        "COLUMN_NAME" => "surname"
    ),
    array(
        "1" => "phone",
        "COLUMN_NAME" => "phone"
    ),
    array(
        "1" => "Name",
        "COLUMN_NAME" => "Name"
    )
);

$new = array_filter($movies);  // Если callback-функция не передана, все значения массива array равные FALSE будут удалены.

$end = array_values($new); // Изъять только значения в массиве

print_r($end);
```

> **array_filter** - Обходит каждое значение массива array, передавая его в callback-функцию. Если callback-функция возвращает true, данное значение из array возвращается в результирующий массив. Ключи массива сохраняются.

Comment: Спасибо. Люблю красивые способы решения задач, без перебора значений, сравнений и т.д.

Comment: @Lenics, всегда пожалуйста:)